# Odoo-8 modify journal items list view

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

In Odoo-8 there is list view for journal items, in that there are two selection field one for `account journal` and second is for `account period`.

[image]

> **What I want to do**
>
> I would like to remove default value from period and journal.
>
> I would also like to filter period in which only open period will be
>   loaded.
>
> **What I have done so far**
>
> I have tried to set default value for period and journal by just
>   setting **_defaults** but then filter wasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file located in:
`addons/account/static/src/xml/account_move_line_quickadd.xml`

This file defines the view you are referring to.

The file:
`addons/account/static/src/js/account_move_line_quickadd.js`

is the js file that sets the default values. If you take a look at the js file you will see that at some point the `default_get` method of the `account_move_line` model is called.

What you can do is either modify the js (by extending the widget of course)
or you can go and override the `default_get` method of the `account_move_line` model and do your work there.